# How to write trigger in oracle to check for one specific condiition

Tags: oracle

I have one table name as user_count_details. There are total 3 columns in this table.

1. msisdn=Which uniquely defines row for one specific user
2. user_count= Which stores the count of user.
3. last_Txn_id= Which stores the last transfer id of txn which user has performed.

The user_count column of this table user_count_details is gets updated with every transaction performed by the user.

But here the logic of my system is

```
select sum(user_count ) from user_count_details
```

will always gives  us the 0 and it is considered as the system is in stable state and everything is fine.

Now i want to write trigger which will check first when new request to update user_count come ,will hamper the sum(user_count )=0 or not and if it hampers that msisdn details will be captured in separate update table.

Comment: Please re-format your question as bullet points, its very difficult to understand what you are asking. Also include any code/queries you have already written

Comment: Didn't get the issue. Please clarify.

Comment: Its not clear from your description on when the user_count column is set to a non-zero value and how it goes back to 0. 1 way I have used previously in such cases is to set add a db trigger which throws an exception for the condition being debugged. The exception can point to the code thats updating the tabls

Comment: Thanks 6 ton for your help till now. But can you please help me to write trigger which will  check whether new update request will violate the sum(user_count) column is 0 or not and if it is not 0 then it will insert new update request of that user in separate table. If you want any more details I can provide.

Comment: Hello Nimesh and 6ton , I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comments, check if this works. Replace the `other_table_name` as per your scenario.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgCheck_user_sum
  BEFORE INSERT
     ON user_count_details FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN      
      IF (select sum(user_count) from user_count_details) > 0 THEN
          insert into other_table_name(msisdn) values(new.msisdn)
      END IF
END
```